# URL Breaks in prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, url, prestashop

I downloaded the theme. The category is added as the menu in navigation bar. When I click on menu. It takes The requested URL ---- was not found on this server. How to fix this.. I dont know where the htaccess file in prestashop. Please guide me to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I fix it using this http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/59954-how-do-i-generate-an-htaccess-file/. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regenerate your .htaccess file under Tools -> Generators